# What's up with jQuery Timeago? I tried everything and still it fails to do anything whatsoever

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetime, jquery-plugins

```
    <abbr class="timeago" title='<%= DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") %>'><%= String.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", DateTime.Now) %></abbr>
```

## +

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('abbr.timeago').timeago();
    });
```

## =

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-29T00:21:40Z">December 29, 2011</abbr>
```

Rendered in the browsers as: December 29, 2011.

Why? Thanks.

### EDIT:

i've resolved this issue had an error in my console.
However, this still fails to do anything when this item is being passed to jquery templates as `${streamObj.DateTime}` =>

```
objStreamItem.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(sqlReader["DateTime"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

Also, the jquery template is loaded from an external js file which in turn is loaded depending on some other page load criteria.

thanks.

Comment: Check the browser's console. Are there errors?

Comment: Also, replace the first code block in your answer (ASP.NET, PHP, whatever that is) with the actual HTML source code that is being read by the browser. Your server-side source code is useless in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me...

HTML:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-29T00:21:40Z"></abbr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( '.timeago' ).timeago();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/B5ebS/

Your code probably throws an error somewhere causing your program to break...